# How to tell where (what cell(s)) an XmlMap is pointing to?

Tags: c#, excel-2003, office-interop

I need to grab the ranges (row, column etc.) a particular XmlMap in an excel worksheet is pointing to programmatically via interop. Does anyone have any thoughts? I can not see any properties/methods/members of the XmlMap interface that provide this information.

Comment: I am going with the Worksheet.XmlDataQuery method to figure this out. But, unfortunately, that method only outputs the range of items I already know exist - but not a listing of all xml-range mappings.

Comment: Please keep your tags in the tags and out of the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by dumping the XmlMap output to a file, using the .NET XML library to find all of the elements in the map and the using 'Worksheet.XmlDataQuery' to find to cell/range location of each element. Its dirty, but its the only way I could get this to work.